# Swagger codegen: generate array elements with the correct names

Tags: openapi, swagger-codegen

I am using swagger codegen with the following YAML snippet:

```
lineItem:
  type: array
  xml:
    wrapped: true
    name: 'lineItems'
  items:
    #xml:
      #name: 'lineItem'
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/lineItem'
```

The object model is serialized to XML and needs to be in the format:

```
<lineItems>
   <lineItem/>
   <lineItem/>
</lineItems>
```

I have referred to the documentation here but cannot get the expected output:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/representing-xml/

I have tried various things but the wrapping element and the individual elements always have the same name! e.g.

```
<lineItem>
   <lineItem/>
   <lineItem/>
</lineItem>
```

What is the correct configuration for this?

Comment: Shouldn't the parent schema be called `lineItemS` (plural)? Otherwise it's a recursive array (array of arrays of arrays ...), which doesn't make much sense in this context.

Comment: If I make it `lineItems` then the elements are also named `lineItems`.

Comment: Can you post a more detailed example of how XML should look like? What's inside individual `lineItem` elements?

Comment: I don't see that that would matter. The issue is referenced here and apparently fixed altough my testing would suggest otherwise. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2316

Comment: Maybe your schema should be structured differently, e.g. not an array of itself, but an array of objects where some property $refs the array. That's why I asked for a more detailed XML example.